# Will e-mail addresses for different domains arrive at the same mailbox if MX records are identical?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

Say I have bluppfisk@bluppfisk.com, but I want bluppfisk@bluppfisk.co.uk to be treated as an alias without setting up a forward. Can I just configure the MX record for bluppfisk.co.uk to point to mailserver.bluppfisk.com?

The reason I'm asking is that I am in the process of transferring domains and I want to test whether everything is working first with a less critcial domain alias (bluppfisk.co.uk) before moving over bluppfisk.com which currently receives all the mail.

Comment: Only if you set up your local MDA to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up the MX record only ensures that delivery attempts get to the appropriate servers.  The rest of this answer assumes that a user has then same user component of the email address across the domains.  Otherwise you will need a user mapping process which is often handed by configuring aliases.

As you seem to have no knowledge about the target MX and MDA servers, changing the MX records does not seem to be an appropriate action.  You may need significant changes on the new MX and MDA servers.

Aliasing domains once you get to the MX depends on the configuration of the MX and the MDA that the email id delivered to.  (The MX and MDA roles may be handled by the same mail server.)

The MX must known that is should be accepting the domain.  If not a properly configured MX will reject the email.  It must also know which MDA to forward the domain to.  Some email software allow rewriting the domain, so the MX could alias the domain before passing the email to MDA.

When the MDA accepts the email for delivery it will determine the appropriate mailbox and deliver the email to the appropriate mailbox.  If the MDA uses the same mailbox for the same userid from all required domains, then you have a possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

`Can I just configure the MX record for bluppfisk.co.uk to point to mailserver.bluppfisk.com?`

Of course. You can point the MX record for any of your domains to any host you choose. The host just needs to be configured to accept email for the domain in question.

Comment: That seems to be the problem then. Unfortunately I have no control of the mailserver at mailserver.bluppfisk.com as it is in the hands of an evil consultancy, so I guess I'll just have to move it without testing and pray.

Comment: Pray all you like,  If the mail server isn't configured to receive mail from `bluppfisk.co.uk`, **this will not work**.